# Multiple constructors with the same number of parameters

Tags: python, constructor, overloading

Is this the correct practice for a class that could be initialized with two different single-parameter constructors? Say the parameter could be either a string or an int:

```
def __init__(self,param):
    if(isinstance(param,basestring)):
        #Initialize using param (string)
    elif(isinstance(param,int)):
        #Initialize using param (int)
    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid param type - must be int or string.")
```

Comment: I'd raise a more specific `TypeError` instead of the generic `Exception`.  You could also get rid of the extra parenthesis `if isinstance(param, basestring):`.  Python isn't C remember. :)

Comment: Could you provide a fuller example? What is the difference between the two cases? It would be more idiomatic to e.g. have a standard `__init__` for the `int` and a `from_string` *classmethod* to parse the string to an integer, if that's what you're doing, but it's hard to advise on such an abstract example.

Comment: @iCodez Haha right, thanks...still transitioning :)

Comment: And in Python 2 probably use one of the number ABCs instead of `int`, since `isinstance(12345678912345678912, int)` is false (it has type `long`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: don't know about idiomatic. Consider `decimal.Decimal`, its constructor takes either. But like you say it's not clear from the question whether that's a good example to follow in this case.

Comment: @SteveJessop that's a fair point. I was thinking more of a situation where you'd parse another representation (e.g. JSON, XML, [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)) to create an instance, but that's a good counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you might be able to do something interesting with [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) in python 3.4. But turns out its a bit cumbersome.

```
from functools import singledispatch

class A:

    def __init__(self, first_arg, another_arg=None):
        A._init(first_arg, self, another_arg)

    @singledispatch
    def _init(arg0, self, arg1):
        raise TypeError(arg0)

    @_init.register(int)
    def _init_int(arg0, self, arg1):
        print('_init_int', arg0, arg1)
        self.arg = arg0

    @_init.register(str)
    def _init_str(arg0, self, arg1):
        print('_init_str', arg0, arg1)
        self.arg = arg0

A(1)
A('str')
class MyInt(int):
    pass
A(MyInt(3))
A([])
```

produces:

```
_init_int 1 None
_init_str str None
_init_int 3 None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multi_init.py", line 32, in <module>
    A([])
  File "multi_init.py", line 8, in __init__
    A._init(first_arg, self, another_arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/functools.py", line 707, in wrapper
    return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
  File "multi_init.py", line 12, in _init
    raise TypeError(arg0)
TypeError: []
```